# Want to know about Service class in Android

Tags: android

I want to make an app in which my audio profile mode change according to location. For this purpose I always need to check location in background. How can I do this in background? Where to right my actual location getting and comparison code in Service class and when to start my service class?

Comment: Use an IntentService and set a PendingIntent after a certain timeframe. You can then request location updates like you do in an activity, get the latitude and longitude, and save them into SharedPreferences. Then, access the SharedPreferences from your activity and do whatever you want with it.

Comment: How could I set pendingIntent?

Comment: And if I use IntentService then behavior of Service class stop after it's defined task is completed. I want to check location without stopping the Service

Comment: continuously checking for location updates isn't a nice practice as it takes up a lot of battery. Instead, define an IntentService that repeats itself in say every 5 to 10 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is an example of IntentService that restarts itself every 5 minutes.

```
public class MyIntentService extends IntentService {

    int updateVal;

    public MyIntentService() {
        super("MyIntentService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

     // your code here. Request location updates here.

    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        //minutes after which the service should restart
        updateVal = 5;

        AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

        //This is to incorporate Doze Mode compatibility on Android M and above.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            alarm.setAndAllowWhileIdle(
                    alarm.RTC_WAKEUP,
                    System.currentTimeMillis() + (1000 * 60 * updateVal),
                    PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, new Intent(this, MyIntentService.class), 0)
            );

        //For all other versions.
        else
            alarm.set(
                    alarm.RTC_WAKEUP,
                    System.currentTimeMillis() + (1000 * 60 * updateVal),
                    PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, new Intent(this, MyIntentService.class), 0)
            );
    }
}
```

In your main activity, type this code to start the service.

```
startService(new Intent(this, MyIntentService.class));
```

You have to implement LocationListener and get the location updates which I haven't added into the code.

If you really wish to start a service that never stops, you need to extend Service class instead of IntentService class. It has been very well explained in the Android Developers guide: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: Thanks to provide example... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use service that return "START_STICKY" in onStartCommand() function. Your service will be restarted again after it was killed by system. However sometimes , it will not be restarted. To make your service 100% alive, use foreground service. Anyway foreground service requires a notification that always shown.